# Weird Shading glitches with models

Tags: modeling

I'm having some weird results when I try to render. Here is the preview, but it looks the same in final. These spheres suddenly won't smooth shade anymore, the tops are glitching, and some results are insane. See the attached images.[image]

Comment: First check for duplicate meshes, then remove doubles. Double check normals, check flat smoothing appears correct and change to a very basic material. Finally upload the file here https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ for us to check.

Comment: Thank you for recommending checking the materials. The normal map was causing a glitch when I packed it into the blend. When I unpacked it and relinked it, it worked.

The viewport glitch was due to the viewport clipping distance being turned too high, I lowered the range and it fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for recommending checking the materials. The normal map was causing a glitch when I packed it into the blend. When I unpacked it and relinked it, it worked. The viewport glitch was due to the viewport clipping distance being turned too high, I lowered the range and it fixed it.